# How to use xlsxwriter to use a string value in format method

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

```
    import xlsxwriter
    wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Format.xlsx')
    ws = wb.add_worksheet('Strings')
    cell_value = 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL'
    cell_frmt = wb.add_format()
    cell_frmt.set_num_format('@')
    ws.write(1,1, cell_value, cell_frmt)
    wb.close()
```

When I open excel I need to just see 'ABCD' when I click on the cell I need to see the full string 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL'.

But when I open the excel I see the full string value. Is there any way to just see the first 4 characters when I open excel and when I click on the cell entire string should be displayed. Please ignore my typos and noobness.

Comment: Is possible to do that in Excel?

Comment: Hi @jmcnamara for number I had used and it worked but for strings (text) not sure. But may be there is a way to do it.

Comment: I think you need to figure that out first. If it is possible in Excel then you can probably do it in XlsxWriter. But the opposite is also true.